# Toggle Button not displaying in app

Tags: android, android-layout, togglebutton

I've created an activity with a toggle button. I've also written the code to handle the clicks.

But when I run the app, the toggle button doesn't show up on the activity screen.

I thought it might be a problem with the emulator so I exported it and tried it on my phone.

But it doesn't show up on the phone also.

Here is the activity layout file description.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Start Notifying" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUserMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnStartService"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWelcomeMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtUserMsg"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Message to reply with" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopNotifying"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnStartService"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Stop Notifying" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnStartService"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtUserMsg"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:text="Caller Notifications" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tglStartStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtWelcomeMsg"
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea why this might be??

Comment: Please post the code where you use the toggle button. I've tested your xml and it works fine. It might be something in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a concept error, when positioning widgets related to others you should do it this way:
 Example:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtWelcomeMsg"
```

Instead of:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtWelcomeMsg"
```

Comment: That did help but I have a question. I didnt add the @+id in the attributes. It was done by the Graphical Layout editor. Does this mean that the layout editor has errors?

Answer (score 1):

generally you use @+id only in the id field. otherwise use @id for all of your assignments.
But this shouldn't cause a problem, please post the code where you use the toggle button.

Comment: Actually changing the @+id to @id fixed the issue and the toggle button started showing up. But I didnt add the + in the attributes. It was done by the graphical layout editor. I think I should stop using the graphical layout editor.

Comment: Yea! sometimes it messes up :)